# Ranking a sum of values whose total is not stored in the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, ranking

I have a table with different exam records of four student all in the same class. The marks have not been summed up in the db. My question is ,is it possible to sum the marks of individual students on the front end and then place a rank on them? I have successfully summed marks on the front end but my rank code isn't working.The first table shows the database record while the second shows the result though the rank is empty :(

[image: preview]

[image: result preview]

here is my attempted rank code

```
    <?php

    $getrnk=$db->query("SELECT SUM(marks)FIND_IN_SET( marks, (    
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( marks
    ORDER BY marks DESC ) 
    FROM examresults )
      ) AS rank
    FROM examresults
    WHERE adm_no ='$reg'");

    $getrnk->execute();

    $rnk=$getrnk->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $strank=$rnk['rank'];
    echo $strank;

     ?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054456/mysql-select-rank-for-users-in-a-score-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is quite clever, so let's work on making it work:

```
SELECT SUM(marks),
       FIND_IN_SET(SUM(marks),
                   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(summarks ORDER BY summarks DESC ) 
                    FROM (SELECT SUM(marks) as summarks
                          FROM examresults
                          GROUP BY adm_no
                         ) sm
                   )
                  ) AS rank
FROM examresults
WHERE adm_no = '$reg';
```

I'm impressed because I would never have thought of using `find_in_set()` to get the rank this way.  Normally in MySQL, one would use variables for the ranking.

Comment: i can acknowledge that your code has displayed a result. The only problem is that the lowest value has been ranked as 1 while the highest as 3rd.what could be the problem?

Comment: @AstroguyPasa . . . Odd behavior.  The problem was the `order by`.  It should have been `order by summarks desc` rather than `order by marks desc`.

Comment: The query has successully worked.Thank you so much. I now need to learn and understand its logics well. :-)